# Python3 | Pyinstaller | how do I add an excel file to the exe

Tags: python, excel, terminal, pyinstaller, exe

I'm trying to create an exe out of a python script that also makes use of an excel file. But everytime I run the exe, I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Example.xlsx'
```

I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong, hope you can help me. My folder contains the following three files:

```
main.py
functions.py
Example.xlsx
```

Next, I run pyinstaller in the terminal:

```
pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "Example.xlsx:." main.py
```

It then creates the dist directory with the main exe in it. But when I run it, it gives me the mentioned error. My main.spec file shows the following for 'datas', what I think is right:

```
a = Analysis(...,
             datas=[('210307 Valuation portfolio (HC).xlsx', '.')],
             ...)
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

This is because pyinstaller extracts to a random temporary location, then runs your file.

This location is accessible using the `sys._MEIPASS` location.

I came across a helper function a couple years ago that makes determining this location during development and deployment quite easy:

```
import sys, os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)
```

To use it, give the function the file name, and it will return an absolute path.

**Edited to include an example**

If you are currently using a call such as:

```
with open("Example.xlsx") as excel_file:
        do_stuff_with(excel_file)
```

Then it would be changed to use the function to find the location:

```
import sys, os

def resource_path(relative_path):
    """ Get absolute path to resource, works for dev and for PyInstaller """
    try:
        # PyInstaller creates a temp folder and stores path in _MEIPASS
        base_path = sys._MEIPASS
    except Exception:
        base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

    return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

with open(resource_path("Example.xlsx")) as excel_file:
        do_stuff_with(excel_file)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand it, but don't really know how to apply it to my case. Should I use this function on the excel file and then run the terminal as follows? "pyinstaller --onefile --add-data "Example.xlsx:resource_path(Example.xlsx)" main.py" Or how else should I fix it?

Comment: @justheretobe This would be added to the python script. You're getting an error that it cannot find the file, because the relative path is not working with the temporary pyinstaller location. In your script you need to use this function to find the absolute path to your packed excel file when you use the file. I can't really provide an example of how to implement it in your code, because I don't know how you're calling it in your code.

Comment: @justheretobe I added the most rudimentary example I can think of.

Comment: @justheretobe To build the .exe the line `pyinstaller --onefile --add-data="Example.xlsx" main.py` should work.